# How to Create a path in svg for d3 brush

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

here what i having a svg like below

currently svg code is like this

```
 <path class="c" d="M-8046.012,2842.011h-1.6" transform="translate(8047.61 -2837.554)"/>
 </g></g></g></svg>
```

and currently this is using groups and path combined and this i want to attach as a d3 brush handle  but here the problem is  currently im creating a brush handle like below

```
const focusHandle = focusBrush.selectAll(".handle--custom")
            .data([{type: "w"}, {type: "e"}])
            .enter().append("path")
              .attr("class", "handle--custom")
              .attr("stroke", "#000")
              .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
              .attr("d", brushResizePath)


const brushResizePath = (d) => {
            var e = +(d.type == "e"),
                x = e ? 1 : -1,
                y = this.height / 2;
            return "M" + (.5 * x) + "," + y + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (6.5 * x) + "," + (y + 6) + "V" + (2 * y - 6) + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (.5 * x) + "," + (2 * y) + "Z" + "M" + (2.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8) + "M" + (4.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8);
        }
```

ex: "M0.5,54A6,6 0 0 1 6.5,60V102A6,6 0 0 1 0.5,108ZM2.5,62V100M4.5,62V100"  like path

so how can i implement the above brush handle to this

Currently my brush is like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few issues with your code here.

Arrow functions don't assign `this`, so `this` in the arrow function is actually the window, I'm not sure if that's intended or not. If you want `this` to be the path, you need to use a function block instead of an arrow function.

Neither the window nor the paths have a `height` attribute, I think you want `innerHeight` instead. If you look at the `d` attribute that gets set on the path in you'll see there's some `NaN`s where you're trying to use `y`.

`brushResizePath` is being used before it's defined, move the definition above the `const focusHandle` bit.

Here's my CodePen with it working: https://codepen.io/Thource/pen/RwWqmZj